# Java consuming too much memory

Tags: java, memory, optimization

I have a java app. Its use is to automate login to websites and create wifi hotspots. It is a GUI app with many features such as a notification manager and system tray. My JAR file has a size of 3 MB but, it consumes about 100 MB of RAM. Should I be worried?

I checked if any of my methods were recursive and I could not find any.

My java app's code can be found here : https://github.com/mavrk/bitm-cyberoam-client/tree/master/JavaApplication13

Comment: ``My JAR file has a size of 3 MB but, it consumes about 100 MB of RAM`` jar size is not directly related to allocated memory in RAM

Answer (score 1):

A one line program can use 8 GB of memory.

If you are concerned about the size of the heap you can either

- reduce it further, though this might slow the application or prevent it from working.
- use a memory profiler to see where the memory is being utilised.
- not worry about about 50 cents worth of memory. If you are minimum wage you shouldn't spend more then 6 minutes on it or your time will be worth more than the memory you save.